# Trigger After Update - New Value keeps the Old values only when updating outside Salesforce (Site)

Tags: apex, trigger, force.com-sites, after-trigger

My purpose is the following:
I have a custom object called "Customer Approvals" and has a lookup to the Opportunity Object. When customer approval record gets to "Accepted", i want to update the Opportunity's stage to "Contract Sent to Customer". Also, after Opportunity moves into that stage, i want to delete all the Attachments from that specific opportunity record. So, at a high level, what i have done is the following:
Trigger on Customer Approvals Object when it is "Accepted", to update the Opportunity's stage --> Trigger on Opportunity Object to delete the Attachments when stage gets to "Contract Sent to Customer".

Problem: When the Customer Approval record is updated from within Salesforce, everything goes fine. However, when the Customer Approval record is updated via Salesforce Sites (i am using an Appexchange app that has a functionality), the new values of the Trigger hold the Old values.
I read [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000323125&type=1&mode=1) article and i understood that maybe i should query the triggered Opportunity records from the database to get the latest values. But still, i get the old stage!!! Is this logical? Could somebody explain me why this is happening?

Code below:
Trigger On Opportunity

```
trigger el_OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after update) {
    system.debug('im here');
    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        system.debug('im in');
    el_OpportunityTriggerHandler.deleteAttachments(trigger.new);
        }

}
```

Handler Class (Logic)

```
public class el_OpportunityTriggerHandler {
    
    public static list<Opportunity> deleteAttachments(list<Opportunity> oppList){
        
        try{
            list<ContentDocumentLink> deleteDocList = new list<ContentDocumentLink>();
            
            for(opportunity opp: oppList){
            

                Id recordTypeCustom = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Custom Pipeline').getRecordTypeId();
                Id recordTypeServices = Schema.SObjectType.Opportunity.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Products/Services').getRecordTypeId();
            
            if(opp.el_Final_Contract_Stage__c == false){
                system.debug('Checbox is: ' + opp.el_Final_Contract_Stage__c);
            if(opp.RecordTypeId == recordTypeCustom || opp.RecordTypeId == recordTypeServices){
                system.debug('Record Type is: ' + opp.RecordTypeId);
                system.debug('Stage is: ' + opp.StageName);
                list<opportunity> currentOppList = [select id, name, StageName from opportunity where id =: opp.id];
                system.debug('Stage is: ' + currentOppList);
                if(currentOppList.size() > 0){
                if(currentOppList[0].StageName == 'Contract Sent to Customer'){
                    system.debug('Stage is: ' + currentOppList[0].StageName);
                  //list<cscfga__Product_Basket__c> syncedBask = [select id, name, csordtelcoa__Synchronised_with_Opportunity__c, cscfga__Opportunity__c from cscfga__Product_Basket__c where cscfga__Opportunity__c =:opp[0].id AND csordtelcoa__Synchronised_with_Opportunity__c = true];  
                    //if(syncedBask.size() > 0){
                      list<ContentDocumentLink> cDocList = [select ContentDocumentId from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId =: currentOppList[0].id];
                        system.debug('Documents List is: ' + cDocList);
                        if(cDocList.size() > 0){
                            currentOppList[0].el_Final_Contract_Stage__c = true;
                            for(ContentDocumentLink contentDoc: cDocList){
                                deleteDocList.add(contentDoc);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
          }
        }
        delete deleteDocList;
            system.debug('Deleted Documents are: ' + deleteDocList);
        return oppList;    
        }catch (Exception e){
            system.debug('Line @ ' +e.getLineNumber() + ' Error: ' + e.getMessage());
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `1st` I am not sure but to have `Trigger.new`  retain old values is not possible, until someone is changing that with some other process. `2nd` Querying the DB wont give you new values as the transaction has bot been committed yet, are you sure there is no recursion happening via some PB, workflow etc. `Trigger.new` should hold the new values, are you sure the appexchange is setting the data correctly?

Comment: Your code has a lot of problems: queries inside a loop, you're not using a DML to update the opportunity record, you can't use AuraHandledException in a trigger context (use addError instead). Realistically, this should be a before update trigger, not after update, in order to update the record correctly.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for your comments, you are right. My only concern is why it should be a before update trigger? I want the attachments to be deleted only when Opportunity stage goes to this specific status. Not before it moves to that status. Also, the reason of not using DML to update my Opportunity is because i want the change to occur in the Attachments of the Opportunity. Thanks for the comments regarding DML in the for-loop and queries as well as the AuraHandled Exceptions. They will be corrected

Comment: Before Update simply means that you're making a change before the record is committed. This is faster than doing a second update after commit. The change will still happen in the transaction where you see the new value, it's simply more efficient. Note how you're trying to update the flag on the opportunity; presumably you want to save this. See [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) for more info.